# Can I use a lexical parameter in a FOR loop select statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use a lexical parameter in a FROM and WHERE clause in a FOR loop. Lexical parameters get populated at run time. I get a compilation error when I try to run it in TOAD:

```
FOR r_inv IN (SELECT i.SERIAL_NO,i.HDD_MODEL,i.HDD_SN FROM inventory i &LP_from) 
LOOP ...
```

Can I even do this? I know that you cannot use lexical parameters with PL/SQL code, but here I am actually trying to use it with SQL statement inside of the PL/SQL code.

The error I am getting is:

> Found '&LP_from', Expecting: `*  +  -  :  CASE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT  CONTINUE  CURSOR  decimal number  EXECUTE  FALSE  float  FORALL  integer  MERGE  MOD  MULTISET  NEW  NULL  PRIOR  REM  SQL  string  THE  TRUE   -or-   (  identifier  REVERSE`

Comment: How are you using this PL/SQL?  You can use substitution variables for anonymous blocks.  Otherwise you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I am using the code in a procedure that get's called by an xml report. I have another procedure that generates a string and passes it to the lexical parameter. My guess is I'll have to create a cursor and use it in my FOR loop.

Comment: What does &LP_from have in it at the point you're trying to execute this?  If it's something like `, table_2 t2 WHERE t2.key = i.key ORDER BY i.key, t2.other_field` then, NO, you can't do that as you have them coded here - you'd need to use dynamic SQL (e.g. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`).

Comment: Thanks Bob, that's exactly what I have in there. I guess I will have to use dynamic SQL then. Thanks again.